# macro for repeated command

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I am a new user to LATEX. I have read a lot of the suggestions done by Ulrike Fischer. She suggested a solution to the problem presented here: 
[xskak displaying certain moves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395946/xskak-displaying-certain-moves)

I found that I use a lot of the command.

```latex
\xskakloop{%
\ifcsempty{Xskak.\xskakgetgame{gameid}.\xskakget{movenr}.\xskakget{player}.nag}
{}
{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }}%
\end{center}
```

How can I turn all those lines into one command? I have read about newcommand but I didn't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Simply surround it with `\newcommand\somecommandname{...}`:

```
\newcommand\myxskakloop{%
      \xskakloop{%
    \ifcsempty{Xskak.\xskakgetgame{gameid}.\xskakget{movenr}.\xskakget{player}.nag}
    {}
    {%
    \getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
    \chessboard[tinyboard,
     pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
      markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
      emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
      \xskakget{opennr}
      \xskakget{lan}
      \xskakget{nag}
      \par
      }}}
```